# UDP client and server not able to communicate across different machines

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to run the UDP client-server example given here: http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html.
When run on same machine by changing  **#define SRV_IP "999.999.999.999"** to  **#define SRV_IP "127.0.0.1"** the program works fine.

However, the same program, where server is placed on one system and the client on the other, and changing  #define **SRV_IP "999.999.999.999"** to  **#define SRV_IP "10.60.5.94"**(this is my server ip) doesn't work. That is Even-though the client sends the the packets to the server's IP, the server is unable to receive it.

Please suggest changes that are required to be performed for the code to run over different machines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like how the artical says `recent (fall 1999) versions of Linux`... "recent" being 14 years ago

Comment: did you open the ports in firewall?

Comment: @oleksii:How do we open the ports in firewall? I'm using fedora 14.

Comment: @Mike: I need the functionality of the article to implement in the code. And as specified the code works fine on same machine. So please suggest some useful links or answers. Thank you

Comment: check if you have a firewall running and then search on how to add a particular port. I only used Ubuntu: there I used an Uncomplicated Firewall (ufw). There are many docs on how to add a UDP port online. This port shall be defined somewhere in your program.

Comment: 1. Define "doesn't work". 2. Are the machines in the same LAN? If not, are the UDP ports you're using open in the router? 3. There isn't nearly enough information here to constitute a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to debug this a step at a time.

1. First use a sniffer on the client machine to make sure that the UDP packet is in fact going out. While you are at it, check the destination address in the packet.
2. Then use a sniffer on the server machine to see of the packet is in fact coming in. The sniffer will catch the packets before they hit the kernel. This will tell you if something on the network or even a firewall on the server is eating the packet.

Good luck.